# Strong Lyapunov Function

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations, differential

By showing that $V(x_1,x_2) = (x_1)^2 + (x_2)^2$ is a strong lyapunov function for the system:

$x_1’ = -x_2$

$x_2’ = x_1 + (x_2)^3 - x_2$

determine a region of ''attraction'' for the origin.

I have the conditions for a strong Lyapunov Function to be:

L1:V(**x**) has local positive definiteness

L2) ΔV(**x**).f(**x**) ≤ 0

L3) ΔV(**x**).f(**x**)=0 if and only if **x**=0

Where ΔV(**x**) = [dV/d$x_1$ dV/d$x_2$]

I found V($x_1,x_2$) to satisfy L1, that the equation is positive definite, 
however I computed ΔV($x_1,x_2$).f($x_1,x_2$) to be ($x_2)^4 - (x_2)^2$ which I thought is always more than or equal to 0, contrary to that it should be less than or equal to zero. 
Moreover, the ΔV($x_1,x_2$).f($x_1,x_2$) equation I have has no $x_1$, so it can equal zero for any $x_1$, which wouldn't satisfy the Strong Lyapunov function conditions. 
Please tell me how to do this, it is driving me insane.

Comment: What's a strong lyapunov function?

Comment: Is this function $V$ locally positive definite? What's the derivative of $V$?

Comment: Why not computing ΔV(x).f(x) and see what happens?

Comment: Indeed $ΔV(x_1,x_2).f(x_1,x_2)=x_2^4 -x_2^2$ hence $ΔV(x_1,x_2).f(x_1,x_2)\leqslant0$ on $|x_2|\leqslant1$, which seems to *determine a region of ''attraction'' for the origin*, no?

Comment: It does, however this wouldnt hold for any $x_1$ and therefore wouldnt give a Strong Lyapunov function?

Comment: Actually the opposite is true: this would fail to hold for **no $x_1$ at all**.

Answer (score 0):

$$V = x_1^2 + x_2^2 $$ is a weak Lyapunov function for this system. Nevertheless you can get some local results since $$ \dot V = 2x_2^4 + 2x_2^2 $$ $$ -2x_2^2(1-x_2^2), $$therefore $$\dot V \leq -2x_2^2, \quad |x_2| < 1.$$ The derivative w.r.t. time of $V$ is negative semidefinite. However since the unique equilibrium of your system is $(0,0)$ the smallest invariant set is also $\underline 0$. Due to Krasovskii-LaSalle theorem the equlibrium is asymptotically stable. Of course, it is merely locally asymp. stable since for $|x_2|\geq 0,$ $V$ is increasing. However, you may find another Lyapunov function which derivative is negative definite, and therefore, a strict Lyapunov function.